# VisualStudio SDK, Runtime update bug

Tags: visual-studio, sdk

I had problem after VS2017 update. I have also installed newest SDK and Runtime (64). I received this error during compilation.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1705  Assembly 'Quizzario.Data' with identity 'Quizzario.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=2.1.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores'
 with identity 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'    
 Quizzario.BusinessLogic    C:\Users\zolty\source\repos\ProjectPwr\Quizzario\Quizzario.BusinessLogic\Factories\ApplicationUserDTOFactory.cs 19  Active
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReInstallation of above packet has helped